# openpyxl does run but did not create any .xlsx file on local desktop

Tags: python, excel, automation, openpyxl

I have installed openpyxl with the command

```
pip install openpyxl
```

```
Requirement already satisfied: openpyxl in c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (3.0.10)
Requirement already satisfied: et-xmlfile in c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (from openpyxl) (1.1.0)
```

And I tried to run this code

```
from openpyxl import Workbook

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active
ws.title = "first"
wb.save('example.xlsx')
wb.close()
```

it does run without any problem

```
C:\Users\User\Desktop\excel_auto>python auto_excel.py

C:\Users\User\Desktop\excel_auto>
```

but it does not create any `.xlsx` or any file.

Comment: Hello, where are you running this script? I ran your code and the file is saved in my current directory no problem.

Comment: I ran this code through vs code and the file is not saved in my current directory.

Comment: Wouldn't it save it in the excel_auto directory?

Comment: Try specifying where you save the excel file to. example `wb.save(r"C:\Users\my_user\Desktop\example.xlsx")`

Comment: @ewong it did not saved in any location

Comment: @MahmudAlptekin it does not work... Do I need to do any other set up other than installing the openpyxl?

Comment: You don’t need to set anything else up. I use pycharm and I copied and pasted your code and it created a file no problem. Tried it on Python IDLE as well with success.So I’m not sure where the problem lies.

Comment: Colour me stumped as well.  That said, add print statements to determine if it really is running through every line.  Check directory permissions (doubt this is the issue).  Use a different filename.  Use a different path.  Other than that...  no clue.  Sorry.

Comment: @김성훈 I would suggest also trying and populating the excel file before saving `ws["A1"] = "Hello world!"` . Or trying to create other file types like `.txt` or `.csv` maybe the problem is with the module itself and needs to be reinstalled.

Comment: first you could use `print()` to see which part of code is executed - maybe you run different script.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help guys! It just worked by uninstalling the antivirus program on my local desktop. Now it works without any issues. Thank you!!